# Png image as html button

Tags: html, image, button, png

I would like to use an icon as a drobdown button on my navbar, but I am new to html and stuff, so I do not know where my snipplet fails:

```
<button type= "image" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">
<img src="someimage.png" title="Some title">
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the issue is most likely with the source of the image. Check the path (where your image is located) and link it correctly.

Example: `src="../folder/folder/image.png"`

You can also add the image as a background with CSS like this:

```
.dropbtn {
  background: url("");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, after some modifications in my css file (on the navbar) this worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to help :) !

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using the button.
Try this:

```
<a href="" class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">
    <img src="someimage.png" title="Some title">
</a>
```